# What tools are available to help organize iOS apps into folders?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad

It used to be the case that we could organize iOS apps on iPhones and iPads by connecting them to a Mac and using some functionality in iTunes.  But with recent changes to iTunes, this is no longer possible.  If you have an iOS device with many apps on many home screens it is now more difficult to organize these apps into folders (by dragging the apps across many home screens).  Can anyone recommend an easier way to accomplish this, including, perhaps, some third-party software that runs on a Mac?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apple Configurator 2, available on the MAS. It's intended as an enterprise tool for those managing lots of iDevices, but works just as well for one. It's fairly self explanatory and graphical in use.

Select your device, then from the menu bar: Actions | Modify | Home Screen Layout. There you can drag Apps about. You can even select multiple apps (Cmd-Click) and move them together.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed Apple Configurator 2 onto my Mac.  However I do not see any functionality that enables the user to organize apps on my iPhone (connected via USB to my Mac) into folders.

Comment: Select your device, then from the menu bar: Actions | Modify | Home Screen Layout. There you can drag Apps about.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect my comment

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional details.  I initially did not see that functionality.  Now I do and am trying it out.

Comment: The functionality is there, but it it seems poorly implemented.  For a user that has many home screens, there is no scroll bar on the configurator, so I have not yet found a way to see all my home screens on the configurator.

Comment: Interesting. Scrolling left & right with the mouse or swiping on the trackpad works fine for me. Also click & drag an app to the left or right moves the app to screens currently hidden. In effect the functionality follows that of the phone, and indeed the previous implementation in iTunes.

Comment: Not sure what explains why it is working for you and not for me.  I am running iOS 11.0.1 on the iPhone and am running 10.13 on the Mac (macOS High Sierra).  I can drag an app to the left or right and, as you described, it can move the app to screens currently hidden.  But I can not otherwise scroll to see screens currently hidden.

Comment: And you have your mouse **on** the screens? It won't scroll unless you are hovering over the app icons. Sorry if this sounds a bit basic and obvious.. What configurator version? Mine is 2.5 and my iOS & MacOS versions are the same as yours.

Comment: I had been using a Logitech mouse.  Horizontal scrolling or dragging didn't work with it.  But now I am trying an Apple Magic Mouse 2, and horizontal scrolling DOES work with it.  It also works with my trackpad, but I had to click down on it first when hovering over the app, presumably to get focus.  There are no scroll bars.  I am using Version 2.5 of Apple Configurator 2 (3F60).

Comment: Having no scroll bars is not unusual for Apple software these days. Mouse issues aside, I think you'll find AC2 is the Apple preferred solution short of reverting back iTunes to a previous version. But then you leave yourself open to security issues and maybe future incompatibilities for the sake of a quite minor function. Apple perhaps should make more effort to document changes and potential replacements in procedure, but there you are. Please feel free to accept my answer when you're ready.